# Why does $(\frac{n}{n+1})^n{\rightarrow}_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{e}$ implies $\frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1}(\frac{n}{n+1})^n|z^2|$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to determine the radius of convergence of the power series $$\sum \frac{(2n)!}{n!n^n}z^{2n}$$

I'm trying to use d'Alembert criterion:

Let be $z\in \mathbb{C},\forall c\in N, u_n=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n^n}z^{2n}$

Then, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

\begin{equation*}
|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}|=\frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1}(\frac{n}{n+1})^n|z^2|
\end{equation*}

Yet,

\begin{equation*}
(\frac{n}{n+1})^n\underbrace{\longrightarrow}_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{e}
\end{equation*}

But why does it implies that

\begin{equation*}
|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}|\underbrace{\longrightarrow}_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{4|z|^2}{e}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because
$$ \frac{2(2n + 1)}{n+1} = \frac{4n + 2}{n + 1} = \frac{4 + \frac{2}{n}}{1 + \frac{1}{n}} \to 4, \ n \to \infty$$
So the product of the limits of the sequences gives
$$ \frac{4 |z|^2}{e}$$